# Matlab mesh to voxel with grayscale values

Tags: matlab, 3d

I'm looking for a way to convert a set of vertices, triangular faces and grayscale texture values to a grayscale volume in Matlab.

Polygon2Voxel works well for binary volumes but I need something similar to generate a grayscale volume. Any suggestions welcome.

Ed

Comment: Can you provide a simple 2D illustration of exactly what you would expect the output to look like?

Comment: Hi Suever. Something like this:   http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/graphi38.gif   By volume I mean a 3D matrix where each voxel value corresponds with a shade.